# How to get distinct year from list of objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, distinct

I've got the following object in Javascript and I'd like to return a list of distinct years from the `createdOn` value:

I've tried the following but it returns an empty array:

```js
const things = [{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "First thing",
    "createdOn": "2017-12-07T15:44:50.123"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Second thing",
    "createdOn": "2018-05-07T09:10:24.123"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "Third thing",
    "createdOn": "2018-12-07T12:07:50.123"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "title": "Forth thing",
    "createdOn": "2018-12-07T16:39:29.123"
  }
]

console.log(things.map(thing => new Date(thing.createdOn).getFullYear()).filter((value, index, self) => self.indexOf(value) === index))
```

What am I missing here?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `thing` instead of `event` in map parameter i.e. `things.map(thing => )` and your code will work. Its TYPO for me

Comment: `new Date(thing.createdOn)` -> `new Date(event.createdOn)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using a misspelled argument in callback to the `.map()` i.e replace `thing` with `event`. You may also use `Set` to get the unique values:

```js
const data = [
  {"id": 1, "title": "First thing", "createdOn": "2017-12-07T15:44:50.123"}, 
  {"id": 2, "title": "Second thing", "createdOn": "2018-05-07T09:10:24.123"}, 
  {"id": 3, "title": "Third thing", "createdOn": "2018-12-07T12:07:50.123"}, 
  {"id": 4, "title": "Forth thing", "createdOn": "2018-12-07T16:39:29.123"}
];

const result = [...new Set(data.map(event => new Date(event.createdOn).getFullYear()))];

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Ahh, you got there before me!  Set is definately the way to go.